# Is there a safe way to tell if a JDBC connection is still ok?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, connection-pooling

We have a web server handling requests from clients. One component of this web server holds a connection to a database.

I need to be able to recognise if the connection has been closed or is in some way no longer functional before I begin to use it. Currently I do something like:

```
// Decide connection details on alias.
private String alias = null;
// I must have my own because I prepare statements.
private Connection connection = null;

public Connection getConnection() {
  try {
    if ( connection.isClosed() ) {
      // Start afresh.
      connection = null;
    }
    // ** More tests here to check connection is ok.
    if (connection == null) {
      // Make a new connection.
      connection = Connections.getConnection(alias);
    }
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
    // Cause a NPE further down the line.
    connection = null;
  }
  return connection;
}
```

Sadly this sometimes returns such a stale connection that I get one of various errors. One such looks like:

> java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

Note that this is just one of the errors recorded and this one happens after about 72 hours idle.

What I am looking for is a minimal database-generic tester of a connection that should consistently tell if the connection is up, running and stable. Is this possible?

I don't mind running a very small query against it but it must be both database agnostic and take little to no time/resources.

BTW: I am running under Java 5 so `Connection.isValid` is not a solution for me.

---

**Added**

For those of you visiting this question later - I eventually took the advice offered and moved to a real connection pool and not only was is astonishingly easy to do but **all** of my issues disappeared.

The only strange part was the realisation that with a connection pool you must `close` your connection when you are finished with it - the pool intercepts the close and returns it to the pool behind the scenes.

Comment: What do you have against ready-made connection pools, which validate connections as a matter of routine?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - nothing - as such - but I have prepared statements attached to these connections so I have to handle them myself. Or do I?

Comment: Actually, that's a concern that these pools also handle, with prepared statement pools. BTW my choice would be *boneCP*.

Comment: Yes, a decent pool should handle this for you.  Your code suggested to me that you've decided to go it alone and do it for yourself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way is to do a simple SQL statement like `SELECT 1` or `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` for Oracle.  (Please see your database for vendor-specific syntax.)

If it fails, refresh the connection.  That's what Java EE app servers like WebLogic do to test them if you configure them to do so.

Comment: I think it'd be advisable if you highlight the fact (which seems a bit implied in your answer) that some application servers already perform this check automatically (if you configure them to do so). WebSphere is a case in point.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon It doesn't work on Informix, Oracle, or DB2.  Just tried it. :)

Comment: @Jeff - I will certainly need either an Oracle version or one that also works with Oracle. `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` seems to be a good suggestion for Oracle but I would prefer just one that is all-encompassing.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: there is none. Oracle and DB2 need special hacks, everyone else uses `SELECT 1`

Comment: How often do you just switch database vendors?  I'm guessing seldom if at all.  If you're really worried, make it a configuration item.

Comment: @duffymo - Customer won't switch database mid-stream but I would certainly like to be able to handle any customer's environment with one code base. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You'll have to figure out how to allow them to add the vendor-specific JDBC JAR to your app and configure the database properly.  Most Java EE apps make that the responsibility of the app server; you use a JNDI data source to look up the database connection and abstract away the details.

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
java.sql.Connection.isValid(int timeout)
```

Returns true if the connection has not been closed and is still valid.

Comment: Sorry - I should have staid I am running under Java 5.

Comment: Just an added bit of info, to my knowledge, the `java.sql.Connection.isValid(int timeout)` method calls `SELECT 1`

Answer (score 5):

Every database has a query that doesn't depend on existing tables. For Oracle, try

```
select 1 from dual
```

For many other databases (MySQL, H2), try

```
select 1
```

DB2 has it's own unique syntax:

```
values 1
```

Comment: DB2 uses this syntax to create ad-hoc tables from a list of values. Search the documentation for `VALUES statement`.

Answer (score 1):

Im my case, I use java.sql.Connection.isValid(int timeout) :

I have a method getConnection (or getInstance no poll in this example) :

```
try {
    if (connect == null) || ! connect.isValid() ) {
        connect.DriverManager.getConnection(...);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    logger.error(...);
    connect = null;
}
return connect;
```

Comment: It is certainly worth having this solution as an option but bear in mind `isValid` is only available in Java 1.6 onwards. Overall - my advice would be *go for a connection pool*.